# Cannot ping from host to host on the same internal network vmware

Tags: networking, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I am simply trying to create two Windows 8.1 Desktop VMs and test network connectivity between the two without binding the network/vSwitch to a physical NIC. I created a standard vSwitch and set the adapters (`E1000`) on the VMs to the correct network. After setting each of their IP addresses they cannot ping each other. Am I missing a step? Are there further instructions anywhere out there that explains how to do this?

Comment: `I crated the vSwitch and set the adapters to the correct network. After setting each of their IP addresses they cannot ping each other` - None of those statements have any meaning without details. What kind of virtual switch did you create? What adapters did you set to the correct network? What network? What are the ip address settings for both virtual machines? What is the OS of the virtual machines?

Comment: @joeqwerty I have edited the question to add detail. Does this clarify the problem a little bit? Sorry about the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

If the VMs are on the same port group, they should be able to talk to each other.